# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics

While I was solving a problem I got stuck here
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)}\cdot\binom{2k}{k}\cdot\binom{n}{k}.$$
I tried to solve this but my progess is nil.
I will be glad if someone could provide me a handy solution.

Thanks

Comment: I've just checked Wolfram Alpha, and the answer seems to come as a hypergeometric function, which means there is no easy simplification.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D0+to+n+1%2F(k%2B1)+c(2k,k)+c(n,k)

Comment: This is the Binomial transform of Catalan numbers: see https://oeis.org/A007317

Comment: @RobertZ. Did you notice the nice asymptotics in the OEIS page ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici You mean $5^{n+3/2}/(8\sqrt{\pi}n^{3/2})$? Very nice indeed.

Comment: @RobertZ. I shall try to work from the asymptotics tomorrow morning. These are very interesting sequences.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

If you look at the $OEIS$ link given by  Robert Z in his comment, you should notice a very simple and interesting asymptotics provided by Vaclav Kotesovec a few years ago;
$$a_n=a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n}{k}}{(k+1)} \sim \frac{5^{n+\frac{3}{2}}}{8 \sqrt{\pi } n^{3/2}}$$ What is  nice is that, as soon as $n\geq 94$, the relative error is smaller than $1$% and, for  $n\geq 937$, this error becomes smaller than $0.1$%.

In the same sprite as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006632/sum-involving-the-product-of-binomial-coefficients/2006730#2006730), it is possible to empirically improve the results using $$a_n \sim \frac{5^{n+\frac{3}{2}}}{8 \sqrt{\pi } n^{3/2}}e^{-\frac 1n}$$ which leads to a relative error smaller than $1$% as soon as $n\geq 12$ and smaller than $0.1$% as soon as $n\geq 72$.

For sure, adding more terms in the correction term improves the results.